# How to calculate the integral $\int \frac{a\tan^2{x}+b}{a^2\tan^2{x}+b^2} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

How to calculate the integral $\displaystyle\int \dfrac{a\tan^2{x}+b}{a^2\tan^2{x}+b^2} dx$?

It seems like a $\arctan$ of what else... but I can not work it out.

I have previously asked how to calculate the definite integral between $0$ and $\pi$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2530338/how-to-evaluate-the-integral-int-0-pi-fracan-sin2xbn-cos2xa2n-si), but the answers there only use complex analysis, so they are of no help for the indefinite integral.

Comment: Can partializing fraction help?

Comment: @Nosrati: all the answers there use complex analysis, whereas here can't be used.

Comment: @Nosrati That question (which was asked by the same person by the way) is about the definite integral, but this one is about the indefinite one. It would be a good idea to add a link in the question and maybe explain the context a bit though, I encourage OP to do that.

Comment: As indicated in my comment above, I think the two questions are different, and the previous answers are not really helpful for the question here. I have edited the question to highlight the distinction (taking the liberty to write as if I was the OP) and voted to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that:
$$\begin{align}
\left(a+b\right)\left(a\tan^2{x}+b\right) & =a^2\tan^2{x}+b^2+ab\left(1+\tan^2{x}
\right) \\[5pt] & = \color{blue}{a^2\tan^2{x}+b^2}+ab\sec^2x\end{align}$$
So we then have:
$$\begin{align}\int \frac{a\tan^2{x}+b}{\color{blue}{a^2\tan^2{x}+b^2}} \,\mbox{d}x 
& = \frac{1}{a+b}\int\frac{\color{blue}{a^2\tan^2{x}+b^2}+ab\sec^2x}{\color{blue}{a^2\tan^2{x}+b^2}} \,\mbox{d}x \\[8pt]
& = \frac{1}{a+b}\int\left( 1 + \frac{ab\sec^2x}{a^2\tan^2{x}+b^2} \right) \,\mbox{d}x \tag{$\star$}\\[8pt]
& = \frac{1}{a+b}\Bigl( x+\arctan\left( \tfrac{a}{b}\tan x\right) \Bigr) +C 
\end{align}$$

---

Where $(\star)$ is a standard integral, or follows after $t=\tfrac{a}{b}y$, here with $y=\tan x$:
$$\int\frac{y(x)'}{a^2y(x)^2+b^2}\,\mbox{d}x = \frac{1}{ab}\arctan\left(\tfrac{a}{b}y\right)+C$$

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int \dfrac{a\tan^2(x)+b}{a^2\tan^2(x)+b^2}\, dx$$ Use $x=\tan ^{-1}(t)$ to make
$$I=\int\frac{a t^2+b}{\left(t^2+1\right) \left(a^2 t^2+b^2\right)}\,dt$$ Use partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{a t^2+b}{\left(t^2+1\right) \left(a^2 t^2+b^2\right)}=\frac{a b}{(a+b) \left(a^2 t^2+b^2\right)}+\frac{1}{(a+b)\left(t^2+1\right) }$$ which looks quite pleasant.

Comment: Note that there is in fact a $t^2$ in the numerator, which makes things look even more pleasant.

Comment: @ComplexYetTrivial. When I wrote *pleasant*, I did not report how many pleasant things are after partial fractions ! Cheers.

Comment: I meant to say that your integrand should be $$\frac{a t^{\color{red}{2}} +b}{(1+t^2)(a^2 t^2 + b^2)}$$ instead of $$\frac{a t +b}{(1+t^2)(a^2 t^2 + b^2)} \, .$$

Comment: @ComplexYetTrivial. Thanks for pointing my typo's !